How can I wrap the child nodes of a <FluentTreeItem> in a <div> without breaking the style?
I am using the TreeView of Fluent UI for Blazor and try to combine it with Sortable JS.
I followed the example of Sortable JS for nested sortables and set everything up - but now I'm having the problem that when I set the class (which is used to find the elements for which a new sortable is created) on the FluentTreeItem itself (the folder in my case) the item isn't draggable. The children, however, work as expected.
I assume that if I wrap all children of a folder in a <div> and set the class there, this problem will be solved. Unfortunately, wrapping the child nodes in a <div>, even without setting a class, messes up the style - especially the expand folder part of the fluent component and the vertical listing.
This is my CustomTreeItem (which uses the FluentTreeItem):
<FluentTreeItem>
  @Node.Name
  <div>
     @foreach (var child in Node.Children)
     {
        <CustomTreeItem Node="@child"></CustomTreeItem>
     }
  </div>
</FluentTreeItem>

Then I use the component for the FluentTreeView:
<FluentTreeView Data="@TreeItems">
    <div>
    @foreach (var node in GetFilterdNodes())
    {
        <CustomTreeItem Node="@node"></CustomTreeItem >
    }
    </div>
</FluentTreeView>

I expect it to look like this
As soon as I insert the <div>

It appears that some of the styles that sortablejs uses are incompatible with the styles that FluentTreeView uses.

I just tried it - a div without a class also messes up the styling... I will adjust my question accordingly!
